# How there is Lvalue required error

Tags: c, lvalue

There is a piece of code which is producing error of "Lvalue required". The code is as,

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<conio.h>
     #define max 10
     int main()
     {
      printf("%d",max++);
      return 0;
     }
```

It was evident that Lvalue error will come in above code so i changed the code to

```
     int a;
     printf("%d",a=max++);
```

I thought now the value of constant is assigned to a proper variable but still the error appeared. Then i checked for

```
     printf("%d",a=max+1);
```

it works without any error.What is the problem with the second piece of code ?

Comment: What do you expect for `10++` ?

Comment: This is something new. +1.

Comment: However, `(a=max)++` would compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max` will be replaced by 10 after preprocessing, so

```
max++ => 10++      //Error  ++ requires lvalue
a=max++ => a=10++  //Error  same as above

a=max+1 => a=10+1 //Works
```

Comment: ++ is an assignment. The same way `10 = 10 + 1` is illegal, `10++` is illegal.

Comment: in the second does it means a=10=10+1 ,thats why its an Lvalue error

Comment: @mrigendra if you think `a=max++` changes to `a=10=0+1` before compilation, that is not the case, however it changes `a=10++` before compilation and "lvalue" is reference to an object that has storage, an identifiable address, "lvalue required error" says that the compiler needs a storage on which it can perform the operation.

Answer (score 5):

`max` is a literal so `max++` will fail. (Just as `10++` will fail).

However, `max + 1` is valid (just as `10 + 1` is).

Remember that `#define`s are resolved by the *preprocessor* which happens *before* compilation takes place.

**To explain your compiler's return error:**

Loosely speaking, an *lValue* is the thing on the left hand side of an assignment; i.e. in

```
a = b;
```

`a` is the lValue. The statement `10 = b;` is clearly meaningless (you can't assign a value to 10): more formally it is invalid since 10 is not an lValue.

Comment: you mean max is a keyword?

Comment: @mrigendra, no you defined it to be the literal 10.

Comment: @mrigendra: it will fail for every word you give it. See my final comment in my (amended) answer.

Answer (score 2):

max is replace by 10 after c preprocessing, which is what `#define` supposed to do.

10 is a rvalue, or literal. No assignment related operation should do to a literal. But `++` operation involves assignment.

For example, you can do `10++;` for the literal 10.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read about compiler macro definitions.

What they actually do is if you type:

```
#define SOMETHING 3
```

is changing every occurrence of something with the further value before compiling the code.

Similar if you use such macro:

```
#define SOMETHING(x) (x + x)
```

It will change the occurrence of SOMETHING(value) to value + value.

The LValue is basically the operand that can be used in the left site of assign operator, in your case it can be a "a" variable.

The value++ is translated to the operation value = value + 1 and wouldn't cause any problems if the variable had been used. You, however had used "max" which is not a variable of any type but its a macro defined from your preprocessor as constant variable. The preprocessor will swap each max to 10 so you end up with the expression 10++ which will evaluate to 10 = 10 + 1 which is just wrong.

Note: you should use defines with capital leather to easier distinguish between variables and preprocessor definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the `++` operator has a *side effect* of updating the value of its operand; for that to work, the operand must be an *lvalue*, which is an expression that refers to a memory location such that the memory may be read or modified; unfortunately,  no memory is set aside for integer constants like `10` , hence the error message.